# Qt mingw32 build Error [debug/rasterwindow.o] Error 1

Tags: qt, build-error

I installed Qt 5.0.1 mingw 4.7, when I build/run an example, I got this at issues:
[image]

and this at Compile Output:
[image]

I can't build/run anything. How to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This was worked for me
Projects > Build > Build Environment:

Check the Clear System environment

follow the following link for more answers
[stackoverflow.com/qt-error-2-at-compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434064/qt-error-2-at-compile-time)

Answer (score 1):

- There are some other issues too. This error is mostly  occurred the
  situations when you run your code one time and again trying to run it
  without closing the previously generated wizard(GUI window).
- QT can't open the target file because it's already in use. So please make sure that you close the generated wizard before run/build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your PATH correctly within your System Environment Variables?

Path Variables I have set for Qt:

`QTDIR: D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32`

Path:
`C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Python33\;C:\Perl64\site\bin;D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin;xxx;D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin;`

** Note: I have read before that ordering can matter. Ensure you have your Qt bin path after your MinGW bin path.

Refer to these discussions:
Similar Issue: [Case 1](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25326/)

If you were able to run programs in previous versions, but cannot now - try this:

1. Clean project
2. Close QtCreator
3. Remove Release/Debug Folder from app directory
4. Delete xxx.pro.user file (lives in app directory)
5. Manually delete Makefile, Makefile.Debug, Makefile.Release (If still there)
6. Open Qt Creator again and open your project. It should now be asking you to reconfigure your project build settings.

Good Luck!