# Compiling QT with MSVC 2012 fails

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I installed QT 5.1 VS2012 release and installed successfuly.
I get error while compilng the project in QT Creator with the 'jom' thingy saying:

```
"jom: F:\tmp2\build-testprj-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2012_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 2
jom: F:\tmp2\build-testprj-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2012_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\moc_mainwindow.obj] Error 2
jom: F:\tmp2\build-testprj-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2012_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
17:30:06: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
```

Error while building/deploying project testprj (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 MSVC2012 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'"

```
    "17:56:29: Running steps for project untitled...
17:56:29: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
17:56:29: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtPrintSupport" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\BAHADI~1.AYD\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.2740.16.jom
jom: F:\tmp2\untitled-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 2
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtPrintSupport" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\BAHADI~1.AYD\AppData\Local\Temp\qcustomplot.obj.2740.16.jom
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtPrintSupport" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\BAHADI~1.AYD\AppData\Local\Temp\dbhelper.obj.2740.16.jom
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtPrintSupport" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\BAHADI~1.AYD\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.2740.32.jom
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtPrintSupport" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\BAHADI~1.AYD\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.2740.32.jom
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtPrintSupport" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtSql" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\BAHADI~1.AYD\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_qcustomplot.obj.2740.32.jom
jom: F:\tmp2\untitled-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\qcustomplot.obj] Error 2
jom: F:\tmp2\untitled-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 2
jom: F:\tmp2\untitled-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\moc_mainwindow.obj] Error 2
jom: F:\tmp2\untitled-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\moc_qcustomplot.obj] Error 2"
```

Comment: and what is the actual error, printed by the compiler?

Comment: it is the only errorenous output of the build process.. i think it compiles but fails after the compilation..

Comment: Are you sure? There's a tab called 'compiler output' in QtCreator, please post a bigger portion of build log from there... Cause jom itself hardly causes errors, most probably there's a compilation error, and less probably errors in the project file.

Comment: i updated the post with the whole build logs..

Comment: A possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434064/qt-error-2-at-compile-time

Comment: Try running nmake in the root of the build folder from a Visual Studio 2012 command prompt